# Network ip Addresses are different

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I know that similar questions have been asked, but couldn't really find anything specific to my situation.

I am on an internal network that has IP addresses in the range NN.1.NN.xxx (NN is a constant that is not 192 or similar home LAN addresses). I have a Wi-Fi access point (wi-fi router with WAN & LAN ports- not mesh) set up and the IP address when connected via ethernet to the access point, is NN.1.NN.xxx.

When connected I can access the devices on the network (printers, etc.). However when I connect via Wi-Fi, the IP address is 192.168.1xx.xxx. Thus I am unable to connect to any of the devices on the network when connected via Wi-Fi.

Any way to change that so that Wi-Fi connections are NN.1.NN.xxxx?

Comment: Do you have DHCP server on router run? If yes check the IP range. Also what happen when you set on device static address for WIFi?

Comment: Is it possible that the Wi-Fi access point router has the DHCP server option enables? It should be off for an access point.

Comment: The main router has DHCP enabled, the WI-Fi Access point has it disabled. NOt sure I understand the question on Device static for WiFi?

Comment: There is zero benefit to masking your internal / private IP addresses, it just means we can't see clearly to assist you - the only exception is if you've actually allocated public IPs to internal hosts (something that many universities still do, but is otherwise quite rare). It sounds like the WiFi and wired LAN are at the very least served by different DHCP servers, are perhaps on separate networks, or known hosts are allocated addresses from a different pool... Is this a home situation, or are you trying to subvert segmentation put in place by an IT depertment?

Comment: Can you show what kind of configuration the Wi-Fi access point _currently has_?